# 'safe' seq() idiom in base R?

Tags: r, sequence

There is a well-known infelicity in base R that `seq(0)` returns `c(1, 0)`, not `integer(0)` as one might expect.

I can write my own "safe `seq()`" function:

```r
sseq <- function(n) if (n==0) integer(0) else seq(n)
```

but I'm curious if there is an existing function/idiom *in base R* that will do this to save me writing this function.

Comment: What is your expected behavior with negative values? `sseq(-2)` returns 1, 0, -1, -2, but `seq_len` (obviously) throws an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specified the `length.out`/`len`/`length` argument of `seq` the output is equivalent to `seq_len`:

```r
seq(len = 0)
# integer(0)

seq(len = 3)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Though according to the documentation `seq_len` is much faster...which has me wondering:

```r
sseq <- function(n) if (n==0) integer(0) else seq(n)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  seq_len(1E6),
  seq(len = 1E6),
  sequence(1E6),
  sseq(1E6),
  times = 30L
)

Unit: nanoseconds
             expr    min     lq        mean median     uq     max neval cld
   seq_len(1e+06)      0    100    286.6667    200    400    1100    30  a 
 seq(len = 1e+06)   6300   6800   9726.6667   7800   9300   26100    30  a 
  sequence(1e+06) 631900 644200 983836.6667 649950 659800 5771700    30   b
      sseq(1e+06)   5900   6100  68686.6667   7150   9300 1827400    30  a
```

Comment: good point, although note that the time unit here is in *nanoseconds* ... so even the slow stuff is pretty fast (I think because `seq()` tries to use ALTREP ...)

Comment: accepting this one because it gives all the alternatives (even though I don't really care about timing much)

Answer (score 9):

`seq_len(0)` returns `integer(0)`, because the single argument is the desired length, not the desired endpoint starting from 1 ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sequence` that has the same behavior than `seq` when provided with an integer:

```r
sequence(0)
#integer(0)

sequence(3)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should explicitly tell the R interpreter what `0` refers to when tempting to call `seq(0)`.

When you type `?seq`, you see the following details

> Typical usages are
>
> ```
> seq(from, to)  
> seq(from, to, by= )  
> seq(from, to, length.out= ) 
> seq(along.with= )  
> seq(from) 
> seq(length.out= )
> ```
>
> The first form generates
> the sequence from, from+/-1, ..., to (identical to from:to).
>
> The second form generates from, from+by, ..., up to the sequence value
> less than or equal to to. Specifying to - from and by of opposite
> signs is an error. Note that the computed final value can go just
> beyond to to allow for rounding error, but is truncated to to. (‘Just
> beyond’ is by up to 10^{-10}10  −10   times abs(from - to).)
>
> The third generates a sequence of length.out equally spaced values
> from from to to. (length.out is usually abbreviated to length or len,
> and seq_len is much faster.)
>
> The fourth form generates the integer sequence 1, 2, ...,
> length(along.with). (along.with is usually abbreviated to along, and
> seq_along is much faster.)
>
> The fifth form generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., length(from) (as if
> argument along.with had been specified), unless the argument is
> numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as 1:from (even for seq(0)
> for compatibility with S). Using either seq_along or seq_len is much
> preferred (unless strict S compatibility is essential).
>
> The final form generates the integer sequence 1, 2, ..., length.out
> unless length.out = 0, when it generates integer(0).

Note that `seq(0)` actually triggers the processing in the 5th use case, i.e., `1:from`, and that's the reason you obtain `1:0`.

To avoid the undesired output like `1:0`, you'd better **specify** the meaning of `0`. In you case, `seq(length.out = 0)` seems the thing you are really after, and this convention enforces you to form a more accurate coding habit :)

Comment: this is not an unreasonable answer, but I think `seq_len(n)` is better than `seq(length.out=n)`; faster *and* less typing.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, that's true. `seq` is generic, which is naturally less efficient than its specific variants like `seq_len`

Answer (score 2):

Actually I like your way of making a safe "`seq`". If you want to shorten the code, probably you can try

```
sseq2 <- function(n) seq(if (n > 0) n)
```

since `seq(NULL)` gives `integer(0)`, so it takes care the cases of `n<1` separately.

## Output Example

```
> sseq2(-3)
integer(0)

> sseq2(0)
integer(0)

> sseq2(5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```